# setInterval animate scroll cross browser

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have small jquery code that scrolls page down and showing table rows.
Table taking with simple_html_dom.php.
Here is working example:
http://www.trip2.am
only frame http://www.trip2.am/arrival/index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".orange_top").after("<div class='blanka'></div>");
setInterval(function(){
var pos = $('html, body').scrollTop();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos + 40}, 200);
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 200);
}
}, 3800)
})
```

working fine in Firefox, IE but in chrome, opera scrolling once. Why?
please help solve this problem.